# How to add a band at the top of the page in html

Tags: css, html

I would like to create a simple HTML page that looks as follows:

[image]

Here is how I wrote my HTML code for the green band, I will not discuss the content of the body (the left, middle, right part) here:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.band-header {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="band-header">
  <header class="site-header">
    <h1>Sample Web Application</h1>
    <img src="image.png" align="right">
  </header>
</div>
```

Here are my questions:
 1. I know that there are many mistakes in my code, the first thing that I didn't get is the **green-coloured header background never appeared**. Even if I changed the CSS to `.site-header`, it still didn't appear.
 2. **How could I make the text `**"Sample Web Application"**` to the bottom left of the green band?** It always appeared on the top left. Is there a bottom-left alignment?
 3. **How could I make the image on the top right of the green band?** I tried align right but it is never positioned to the top left. Is there a way to position it on the right and on the top?

I know it's a lot of questions and I am just a newbie at HTML and CSS. Could anyone please give some lights? I really appreciate it. Many thanks.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `align` as an attribute for `img` is deprecated in HTML 5 and should not be used.

Comment: Also when you post as separate questions, be sure to explain (with code samples) what you’ve tried and what the result was

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the suggestion. I have made some edits focusing only on the questions related to the green band.

Answer (score -1):

1. The green color appears in your code, but the header does not have a specified height. It is therefore as high as its highest child element. Below I made the header 100px high which allows for bottom and top alignment of the child elements.

2 + 3: The container (header) is defined as a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). This allows for alignment options of its child elements (items).

```css
.band-header>header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.band-header>header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: flex-end; /* put it at the bottom */
}

.band-header>header img {
  align-self: flex-start; /* put it at the top */
}
```

```html
<div class="band-header">
  <header class="site-header">
    <h1>Sample Web Application</h1>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </header>
</div>
```